# I got these error when validating my code on W3

Tags: html, validation

I put this code on W3 validator: `<img scr="https://placebear.com/800/700" alt="bears"><br><br>`

and got these two errors:

> Attribute scr not allowed on element img at this point.

> Element img is missing required attribute src.

anyone knows why?

Comment: of course, because (1) you are using the attribute `scr` in a `img` and is not allowed, and (2) because you're missing the attribute `src` for your `img`... this is also called TYPO.... you misspelled the name of the attribute

Answer (score 0):

`<img scr="https://placebear.com/800/700" alt="bears"/>` should be changed to `<img src="https://placebear.com/800/700" alt="bears"/>` **src has typo.**